# Trouble understanding navbar dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, navbar

I'm trying to make a nav bar I found on CodePen, but the problem is it doesn't have a dropdown menu. I know how to make a dropdown menu, but don't know how to position and style it as of now. I'm still fairly new to CSS.

Any help is very much appreciated, thank you!

*If the code is not responsive, here's the original.*
https://codepen.io/WebDevSimplified/pen/LqKQRK

```
<nav class="navbar">
  <a div class="brand-title" href="submissions.html">AESTHETIC PRESS</a></div> 
  
  <a href="#" class="toggle-button">
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
  </a>
  <div class="navbar-links">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"> Books</a></li>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Young Adult</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Adult</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Non-Fiction</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
      <li><a href="#">Author</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
 <ul>
      <li><a href="">Our Team</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
  
  <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
   
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us <i class="fa-solid fa-caret-down"></i></a>
    <ul>   
      <li><a href="submissions.html">Submissions</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Permissions</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Translation</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Press</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Hiring</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
  </li>
  </div>
</nav>
```

```
.navbar {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
  height: 100px;
}

.brand-title {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2.0rem;
  margin: 1.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.brand-title:hover {
  color: white;
}
.navbar-links {
  
  padding: 0px;
  
  margin-right: 35%;
  border: red dotted 3px;
}

.navbar-links ul {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar-links li {
  list-style: none;
}


.navbar-links li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.navbar-links li:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

.toggle-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: .75rem;
  right: 1rem;
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 30px;
  height: 21px;
}

.toggle-button .bar {
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .navbar {
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: flex-start;
  }

  .toggle-button {
      display: flex;
  }

  .navbar-links {
      display: none;
      width: 100%;
  }

  .navbar-links ul {
      width: 100%;
      flex-direction: column;
  }

  .navbar-links ul li {
      text-align: center;
  }

  .navbar-links ul li a {
      padding: .5rem 1rem;
  }

  .navbar-links.active {
      display: flex;
  }
}
```

Comment: Well problem is that your code post here does not have the include js from the original post. The js add/remove a class (`active`) to `navbarLinks` when you click on the bars

Comment: Please confirm your question about are you asking to convert your menu as a dropdown or want to add a dropdown item in the menu? 
Because! In the codepen, the menu is already responsive and working as a dropdown on screens that sizes below or equal to 800px.

Comment: Use a formatter on your HTML code and you'll find that your unordered list is malformed. By my count, you're missing 3 `<li>` tags, and a `</ul>` tag.

Comment: @RajpalSingh The question is that I have trouble with the margin. I want the UL bar on the right but it won't work.

Comment: How do I style the dropdown menu in css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want nested dropdown in navigation link. Also you can use [bootstrap navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navbar/) or [w3school navbar](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_subnav.asp).

```js
(function($) { // Begin jQuery
  $(function() { // DOM ready
    // If a link has a dropdown, add sub menu toggle.
    $('nav ul li a:not(:only-child)').click(function(e) {
      $(this).siblings('.nav-dropdown').toggle();
      // Close one dropdown when selecting another
      $('.nav-dropdown').not($(this).siblings()).hide();
      e.stopPropagation();
    });
    // Clicking away from dropdown will remove the dropdown class
    $('html').click(function() {
      $('.nav-dropdown').hide();
    });
    // Toggle open and close nav styles on click
    $('#nav-toggle').click(function() {
      $('nav ul').slideToggle();
    });
    // Hamburger to X toggle
    $('#nav-toggle').on('click', function() {
      this.classList.toggle('active');
    });
  }); // end DOM ready
})(jQuery); // end jQuery
```

```css
.navigation {
     height: 70px;
     background: #262626;
}
 .brand {
     position: absolute;
     padding-left: 20px;
     float: left;
     line-height: 70px;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     font-size: 1.4em;
}
 .brand a, .brand a:visited {
     color: #fff;
     text-decoration: none;
}
 .nav-container {
     max-width: 1000px;
     margin: 0 auto;
}
 nav {
     float: right;
}
 nav ul {
     list-style: none;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
}
 nav ul li {
     float: left;
     position: relative;
}
 nav ul li a, nav ul li a:visited {
     display: block;
     padding: 0 20px;
     line-height: 70px;
     background: #262626;
     color: #fff;
     text-decoration: none;
}
 nav ul li a:hover, nav ul li a:visited:hover {
     background: #2581dc;
     color: #fff;
}
 nav ul li a:not(:only-child):after, nav ul li a:visited:not(:only-child):after {
     padding-left: 4px;
     content: ' ▾';
}
 nav ul li ul li {
     min-width: 190px;
}
 nav ul li ul li a {
     padding: 15px;
     line-height: 20px;
}
 .nav-dropdown {
     position: absolute;
     display: none;
     z-index: 1;
     box-shadow: 0 3px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
/* Mobile navigation */
 .nav-mobile {
     display: none;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     right: 0;
     background: #262626;
     height: 70px;
     width: 70px;
}
 @media only screen and (max-width: 798px) {
     .nav-mobile {
         display: block;
    }
     nav {
         width: 100%;
         padding: 70px 0 15px;
    }
     nav ul {
         display: none;
    }
     nav ul li {
         float: none;
    }
     nav ul li a {
         padding: 15px;
         line-height: 20px;
    }
     nav ul li ul li a {
         padding-left: 30px;
    }
     .nav-dropdown {
         position: static;
    }
}
 @media screen and (min-width: 799px) {
     .nav-list {
         display: block !important;
    }
}
 #nav-toggle {
     position: absolute;
     left: 18px;
     top: 22px;
     cursor: pointer;
     padding: 10px 35px 16px 0px;
}
 #nav-toggle span, #nav-toggle span:before, #nav-toggle span:after {
     cursor: pointer;
     border-radius: 1px;
     height: 5px;
     width: 35px;
     background: #fff;
     position: absolute;
     display: block;
     content: '';
     transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}
 #nav-toggle span:before {
     top: -10px;
}
 #nav-toggle span:after {
     bottom: -10px;
}
 #nav-toggle.active span {
     background-color: transparent;
}
 #nav-toggle.active span:before, #nav-toggle.active span:after {
     top: 0;
}
 #nav-toggle.active span:before {
     transform: rotate(45deg);
}
 #nav-toggle.active span:after {
     transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
 article {
     max-width: 1000px;
     margin: 0 auto;
     padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<section class="navigation">
  <div class="nav-container">
    <div class="brand">
      <a href="#!">Logo</a>
    </div>
    <nav>
      <div class="nav-mobile"><a id="nav-toggle" href="#!"><span></span></a></div>
      <ul class="nav-list">
        <li>
          <a href="#!">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#!">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#!">Services</a>
          <ul class="nav-dropdown">
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Web Design</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Web Development</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Graphic Design</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#!">Pricing</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#!">Portfolio</a>
          <ul class="nav-dropdown">
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Web Design</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Web Development</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Graphic Design</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#!">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</section>

<article>
  <h2>Navigation</h2>
  <p>Responsive Dropdown Navigation Bar.</p>
</article>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for helping out! Is there anyway I could make the dropdown menu activate when hovering the button instead of pressing it?

Comment: No it's not appropriate to add hover in mobile view. Because when you surf any website through phone, obviously you click anywhere on phone screen because there is no mouse cursor. If you want to add hover effect on hamburger, I suggest that make hamburger from the desktop view.

Comment: The website will mainly be used on desktop. Is there any way to add hover and click. So hover for desktop and click for mobile?

Answer (score 0):

Accordingly to your reply to my comment I have added some code to yours.
So please check the code from https://codepen.io/13rpsingh/pen/poajyXK

```js
window.addEventListener("load", ()=>{
  
  let toggleButton = document.querySelector(".toggle-button");
  let navbarLinks = document.querySelector(".navbar-links");
  toggleButton.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
    if(navbarLinks.classList.contains("active")){
      navbarLinks.classList.remove("active")
      toggleButton.classList.remove("active")
    }else{
      navbarLinks.classList.add("active")
      toggleButton.classList.add("active")
    }
  })
  
  
  let menuDropDown = document.querySelector(".navbar-links ul li ul");
  let dropDownTrigger = document.querySelector("#dropdown-trigger");
  
  if(dropDownTrigger){
    dropDownTrigger.addEventListener('click', (e) =>{
      if(menuDropDown.style.display == "flex"){
        
      menuDropDown.style.display = "none";
      }else{
       
      menuDropDown.style.display = "flex"; 
      }
    })
  }
})
```

```css
.navbar {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
  height: max-content;
  max-width:100%;
}

.brand-title {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2.0rem;
  margin: 1.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.brand-title:hover {
  color: white;
}
.navbar-links {
  
  padding: 0px;
  
  margin-right: 35%;
  border: red dotted 3px;
}

.navbar-links ul {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar-links li {
  list-style: none;
}


.navbar-links li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.navbar-links li:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

.toggle-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: .75rem;
  right: 1rem;
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 30px;
  height: 21px;
}

.toggle-button .bar {
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .navbar {
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: flex-start;
  }

  .toggle-button {
      display: flex;
  }
  
  .toggle-button .bar{
      position: absolute;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  }
  .toggle-button .bar:nth-of-type(1){
      top: 0;
  }
  .toggle-button .bar:nth-of-type(2){
      top: 50%;
      transform : translateY(-50%);
  }
  .toggle-button .bar:nth-of-type(3){
      bottom: 0;
  }
  .toggle-button.active .bar:nth-of-type(1){
      top: 50%;
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translateY(-50%);
  }
  .toggle-button.active .bar:nth-of-type(2){
      display:none;
  }
  .toggle-button.active .bar:nth-of-type(3){
      bottom: 50%;
    transform: rotate(45deg) translateY(50%);
  }

  .navbar-links {
      display: none;
      width: 100%;
  }

  .navbar-links ul {
      width: 100%;
      flex-direction: column;
  }

  .navbar-links ul li {
      text-align: center;
    position:relative;
  }

  .navbar-links ul li a {
      padding: .5rem 1rem;
  }

  .navbar-links.active {
      display: flex;
  }
}

.navbar-links ul li ul{
  display:none;
  flex-direction: column;
  position:absolute;
  background:#d0d0d0;
  max-width: 100%;
}


.navbar-links ul li ul li a{
  color : black; 
}


.navbar-links ul li ul li a:hover{
  color : white; 
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <a div class="brand-title" href="submissions.html">AESTHETIC PRESS</a></div> 
  
  <a href="#" class="toggle-button">
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
  </a>
  <div class="navbar-links">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"> Books</a></li>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Young Adult</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Adult</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Non-Fiction</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
      <li><a href="#">Author</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
 <ul>
      <li><a href="">Our Team</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
  
  <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
   
    <li id="dropdown-trigger"><a href="#">Contact Us <i class="fa-solid fa-caret-down"></i></a>
    <ul>   
      <li><a href="submissions.html">Submissions</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Permissions</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Translation</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Press</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Hiring</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
  </li>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Maybe, you can easily understand the code which I added.

I hope It will help